# Implementing simple Modal in Django application

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am struggling with implementing my codepen javascript based Overlay Modal in my Django application. [This](https://codepen.io/rapaccinim/pen/NWjpeVq) codepen contains the HTML, CSS, and Javascript code for my modal, and is functional. As you can see in the HTML I have posted bellow, I have a simple page where a user can look at donations, and if they want to see about it, they can click on the view button. When this button is clicked, I want to bring up an overlay like in the codepen, but it is not working. I can't figure out why. I assign all of the proper ids and classes to elements, but my program does not do anything. Can some expert please help :)? My html is down bellow.

```
{% extends 'suppliesbase.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for donation in donations %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{donation.imageURL}}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>{{donation.title}}</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" id="openModalBtn" href="#">View</a>
                
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>Free!</strong></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
  

{% endblock content %}



<div id="modal-overlay">
    <div id="modal">
      <div class="head">
        <a id="close-modal-button" href="javascript:;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">Modal content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Please reach out if you have any questions. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

```
{% extends 'suppliesbase.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for donation in donations %}
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{donation.imageURL}}">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>{{donation.title}}</strong></h6>
                <hr>

                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="openModalBtn" href="#">View</button>
                
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>Free!</strong></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
  


    <!--Modal Overlay Content -->
    <div id="modal-overlay">
    <div id="modal">
      <div class="head">
        <a id="close-modal-button" href="javascript:;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">Modal content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
        var openModalButton = document.getElementById("open-modal-button");
var closeModalButton = document.getElementById("close-modal-button");

var modalOverlay = document.getElementById("modal-overlay");
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

// function that open modal and display the overlay
openModalButton.addEventListener("click", event => {

    modalOverlay.classList.add("modal-overlay-visible");
    modal.classList.add("modal-visible");

});


// function that closes the modal and remove the overlay
closeModalButton.addEventListener("click", event => {

    modalOverlay.classList.remove("modal-overlay-visible");
    modal.classList.remove("modal-visible");

});
    </script>
    

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>

<style>
#open-modal-button {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -75px;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font: 1.125em "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(217, 67, 86, 1);
}

#modal-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 257, 153, 0.75);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#modal-overlay.modal-overlay-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#modal {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 50% 0 0 -300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#modal.modal-visible {
  margin-top: -200px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.head {
  width: 90%;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 1.5em 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #01bce5;
}

#close-modal-button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

#close-modal-button::before,
#close-modal-button::after {
  content: "";
  width: 32px;
  height: 6px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

#close-modal-button::before {
  margin-top: 12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-modal-button::after {
  margin-top: -6px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.content {
  padding: 5%;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="box-element product">
                <h6><strong>abcd</strong></h6>
                <hr>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" id="open-modal-button" href="#">View</a>
                <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>Free!</strong></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <div id="modal-overlay">
    <div id="modal">
      <div class="head">
        <a id="close-modal-button" href="javascript:;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">Modal content</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
  

  
  
  <script>
  var openModalButton = document.getElementById("open-modal-button");
var closeModalButton = document.getElementById("close-modal-button");

var modalOverlay = document.getElementById("modal-overlay");
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

// function that open modal and display the overlay
openModalButton.addEventListener("click", event => {

    modalOverlay.classList.add("modal-overlay-visible");
    modal.classList.add("modal-visible");

});


// function that closes the modal and remove the overlay
closeModalButton.addEventListener("click", event => {

    modalOverlay.classList.remove("modal-overlay-visible");
    modal.classList.remove("modal-visible");

});
  
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I included that at the bottom of my code, but still nothing happens. I will update my question.

Comment: Updated my question, still confused as to why the code is not working

Comment: Hey I can donate a coffe if you help me resolve the problem

Comment: Haha... no need... I have updated the answer for just one record... removed the for loop and other python stuffs... you can update your html pythonic way according to your need...

Answer (score 0):

You should put your HTML modal and script tag inside your `{% block content %}`

In Django if you `{% extends ... %}` your base template and put any code outside `{% block .... %}`  it will not be included in your template because there was no block for that code to be included in

And HTML Models are hidden by default and they are only visible when View button is pressed no matter where you put them in your HTML code.(the shape might differ if you put them inside any other tag)

Comment: Not working for some reason, the text Modal Content shows up when it should only show up if the view button was clicked

Comment: so now the problem is that the modal always shows up when the html page is rendered... then its the error is your model ... either it is poorly configured or there is something wrong with its css properties ..... i am not very good at frontend but according to me in your case your modal is lacking of many properties .... if you are using bootstrap this might help [bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: I figured out why it was showing up, and I fixed that. Everything works, except the modal does not open when the view button is clicked. I suspect it has something to do with the javascript. I will update my question to include my current code

Comment: I have updated my question to include my code

Comment: if your are using bootstrap you should definitely check bootstrap modals link i have provided in my last comment you will know what i am talking about Or if you are writing your custom models then sorry i am no expert in java script i always copy my html code from other websites and the snippets from codepen specially do not work in my case they only work in their website only